# Glue vs Automapper vs Emit vs ValueInjecter entity mappers

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, mapper, valueinjecter

I'm working on a DDD project where a lot of field mapping is going on. I'm looking for a fast and solid mapping library as opposed to writing all the mappings by hand and there seems to be a lot of options out there.

At the moment I'm leaning more towards Glue as it looks to offer quite a bit of functionality and is also built with unit testing in mind which is also important to the project I'm working on. On the down side its only been downloaded 200+ times which leads me to think that something like ValueInjecter might be a better choice as there's more support out there for it.

My question is, is Glue better or worse than any of the other mappers out there? Or are the differences between the mappers mentioned above negligible in terms of performance and usability?

Answer (score 6):

Personally I would go with either `AutoMapper` or `ValueInjector`. I have used both before and they are extremely fast and stable. Depending on your needs there are things that ValueInjector does that AutoMapper does not (like easily left to right and right to left mappings), so I suspect that ValueInjector may be the most suitable.

The statement about Glue being built with unit testing in mind this shouldn't really influence your decisions as you will most likely be using the assemblies via NuGet and thus using the complied assemblies rather than building from the source code.

Comment: Thanks mate, think I'll give ValueInjecter a go.